# Forcing App to Navigate to a specific view within AppDidBecomeActive

Tags: ios, memory-management, view

I want to let the user be able to navigate to a specific view under certain circumstances, when the App runs again from the background.

For now I'm using this piece of code to force my App:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
                        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
                        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

                    return YES;
            }

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
        if(this situation occurs){
                NavigationViewController *vc = [[NavigationViewController alloc] init];
                            self.window.rootViewController = vc;
                            [vc release];
        }
        eles{
                Password *vc = [[Password alloc] init];
                            self.window.rootViewController = vc;
                            [vc release];
        }
}
- (void)dealloc {
                    //[password release];
                    [_window release];
                    [_viewController release];
                    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

However I think my previous view is still running somehow (a timer still runs).  How am I able to release the previous view ans start 'clean' again.

### EDIT:

The solution was to check if the window has a subview. If it has it will be removed from the superview. Afterwords the new view is created and added to the view as a subview

```
for (UIView *subView in [self.window subviews]) {
                [subView removeFromSuperview];
            }


            self.viewController = [[[MyNewNibFile alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyNewNibFile" bundle:nil] autorelease];
            [self.window addSubview:self.viewController.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make  global instance of NavigationViewController  and password i.e. declare them in appdelegate.h
and before creating new instance of navigation controller and password always check if they are already created or not.If they are already created then release them first and then create a new instance .

Comment: Can you explain your answer in code in code? Is it good enough to set the password en navigationViewcontroller as a property. -> synthesize -> use self.window.rootViewController = self.Password; and release them in dealloc?